# Как добавить картинку в начало pdf файлa?

Tags: c#, pdf

Имеется pdf файл, как вставить в его начало картинку?
Необходимо вставить в начало документа и сам документ сдвинуть вниз.

Comment: Полно либ для работы с pdf файлами.

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/583629/6766879

Answer (score 0):

Например, с использованием библиотеки [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/):

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var imagePath = @"...\image.jpg";
        var srcPath = @"...\source.pdf";
        var destPath = @"...\destination.pdf";
        using (var destStream = File.OpenWrite(destPath))
        using (var reader = new PdfReader(srcPath))
        using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, destStream))
        {
            var pdfConvertByte = stamper.GetOverContent(1);
            var image = Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
            pdfConvertByte.AddImage(image);
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Источник: [How can I insert an image with iTextSharp in an existing PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/583629/6766879)</sub>

Comment: Необходимо вставить в начало документа и сам документ сдвинуть вниз

Comment: Хорошо, сдвигайте.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример как это сделать

Comment: В общем случае это может быть невозможно. Почему вы открываете существующий pdf? Нельзя подготовить такой шаблон, чтобы вставлять в него картинку можно было без сдвигов?